# Mean Stack -> Sequelize Mysql Association

Tags: mysql, angularjs, sequelize.js, mean-stack

I am trying to create an association between two tables. I am receiving an error that the tables are not associated.

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

var Product = sequelize.define('Product', {
        name:               DataTypes.TEXT,
        description:        DataTypes.TEXT,
        manufacturer:       DataTypes.CHAR(150),
        stockCode:          DataTypes.CHAR(150),
        price:              DataTypes.FLOAT,
        weight:             DataTypes.FLOAT,
        stockLevel:         DataTypes.FLOAT,
        imageUrl:           DataTypes.STRING,
        category:           DataTypes.CHAR(50),
        pathId:             DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
        sku:                DataTypes.CHAR(64),
        upc:                DataTypes.CHAR(64),
        ean:                DataTypes.CHAR(64),
        jan:                DataTypes.CHAR(64),
        isbn:               DataTypes.CHAR(64),
        stockStatusId:      DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
        imageDest:          DataTypes.TEXT,
        image:              DataTypes.TEXT,
        points:             DataTypes.INTEGER(8),
        shipping:           DataTypes.INTEGER(1),
        dateAvaliable:      DataTypes.DATE,
        weightClassId:      DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
        lengthClassId:      DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
        length:             DataTypes.DECIMAL(15,8),
        width:              DataTypes.DECIMAL(15,8),
        height:             DataTypes.DECIMAL(15,8),
        subtract:           DataTypes.INTEGER(1),
        minimum:            DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
        sortOrder:          DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
        tag:                DataTypes.TEXT,
        metaTitle:          DataTypes.CHAR(255),
        metaDescription:    DataTypes.CHAR(255),
        metaKeyword:        DataTypes.CHAR(255),
        discontinued:       {
            type            :DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
            defaultValue    : 0
        },
    },
    {
        associate: function(models){
            Product.belongsTo(models.Supplier);
            //Product.hasMany(models.ProductCategoryMatch);
        }
    }
);

return Product;
```

};

and

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

var ProductCategoryMatch = sequelize.define('ProductCategoryMatch', {
        total:              DataTypes.INTEGER,
        count:              DataTypes.INTEGER,
        productId:          DataTypes.INTEGER,
        // categoryId:          DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
    {
        associate: function(models){
             ProductCategoryMatch.belongsTo(models.Product, {foreignkey : 'ProductId'});
            // ProductCategoryMatch.belongsTo(models.Category, {foreignkey : 'categoryId'});
        }
    }
);

return ProductCategoryMatch;
```

};

I am pretty sure the table is creating correctly

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ProductCategoryMatches` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment , `total` INTEGER, `count` INTEGER, `ProductId` INTEGER, `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), FOREIGN KEY (`ProductId`) REFERENCES `Products` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE) ENGINE=InnoDB;

Then when I try to find I get an error
Error: ProductCategoryMatch is not associated to Product!

/**
 * List of Products and there categories
 */
exports.categories = function(req, res) {

```
db.Product.findAll({
    attributes : [
        'name',
        // 'ProductCategoryMatch.count'
    ],
    include : [
        { model: db.ProductCategoryMatch }
    ],
    // order : [

    // ]
}).then(function(products){
    return res.jsonp(products);
}).catch(function(err){
    return res.render(500, {
        error: err,
        status: 500
    });
});
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in the code you posted above, the association from Products to ProductCategoryMatch is commented out:

```
associate: function(models){
  Product.belongsTo(models.Supplier);
  //Product.hasMany(models.ProductCategoryMatch);
}
```

Not sure if that's just the sample code you have posted, but the way the Sequelize associations work is on a per model basis.

So, the association to Products on ProductCategoryMatch will work on an include

```
include: [{ model: db.Product }]
```

but you have to explicitly add the association to Product to make the include work the other way:

```
include: [{ model: db.ProductCategoryMatch }]
```